# Get list of comma separated names into data validation dropboxes?

Tags: vba

I have a list of names in VBA:

```
Dim names as Variant
vNames = GetNames with some function
'vNames(1) = "Joe"
'vNames(2) = "Sarah"
'vNames(3) = "Lisa"
'vNames(4) = "Erik"
```

I want to use these as alternatives in data drop down fields in many cells.

How do I get that variant array into data drop down fields?

Comment: Try recording a macro while adding a list of values via Data Validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making your variant array a string array and using the following:

```
Sub CreateValidation()

Dim sNames()    As String
Dim allNames    As String

'sNames = GetNames with some function
sNames = Split("Joe,Sarah,Lisa,Erik", ",") 'Used as an example

allNames = Join(sNames, ",")

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=allNames
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

**Notes**

1. Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name.
2. Replace "A1:D10" with your range that needs validation.